# not responding in windows task manager

Tags: unity-game-engine, taskmanager

my windows build unity runtime shows "not responding" in task manager.
but works fine.
gameobjects moves fine,
input and controls fine,
receiving data is fine.
just shows "not responding" in windows task manager.
is there any solutions?

OS : Windows server 2012 r2
cpu usage : 5~10%
memory usage : 260MB / 32GB

Comment: Depending on what’s on your server there are a lot of things that can drag it down. I know if I build on my own machine a specific build took 6.5 minutes. On my work machine 6.5 HOURS

Comment: Unity builds always consume alot of CPU because of native code compilation.